# how to match server database in our local database table in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend
 can any one tell me that i have web server there i have create the database for store some value for registration form the value was save in webserver this is working good

but now that data coming in json format and now i have fetch json value and save in to the local database which is same as the webserverdata base both the side ssame table and same colume name is there how can i do this

and how to writ the query for this sitution help me

Comment: To be honest, I've no idea what you really want to do ...

Comment: friend i want that , i have xib and that xib name is mapper ok and this xib i have one tab bar button and in this tabbar i give link of web server page which direct open the user registration from and user can fill there from easy ok on the registration from have submit button if user submit there data then after i have fast retrive there data from server database which user fill on registration from and that i have get username and password bec after the registration from complete then user come on login pagexib in this xib i have give authrity

Comment: authority to user please enter ur username and password if user enter there username and password he should chek from database it this username have or not and this all information i have to store from server to local database after this hapen then i have to match username and password from local database which i am sqlitedatabase it this possbel friend if yes then give me some information about yhis type of database save and retrive in iphone and please give me some small code of this releted this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various JSON parsers exist for objective c.  You'll have to pass the data to a library or to javascript in a webview to extract it.  Here is a google library: 
http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

If you need help with saving the data, I say with no snideness whatsoever that you should read the manual:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html

In